# Facebook Graph API location data missing, but visible on FB site search?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm noticing an inconsistency with the FB Graph API.

Suppose I'm logged in (and have access_token for) user Bob. Bob isn't friends with user Jim.

If I, as Bob, via the Graph API, ask for data about Jim:

`https://graph.facebook.com/jim?access_token=blah&fields=location,hometown,name,id,address`

I get a structure like this back:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Jim"
}
```

Note that the fields that I've requested are conspicuously missing.

However, if I log in to the FB website as Bob, and then *search* for Jim, I can see his location and hometown on his "About" page, *even if* I'm not friends with him.

Why is this? Is there some additional token permission I have to specify or field I need to ask for in order to get this data (which is evidently rather public) from the API?

Comment: Is your access token an app access token that you retrieved via a call to `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token`?

Comment: I've tried now with both an app and user access token, and get the same results - no location or hometown fields in the results!

Comment: Cross Check your facebook profile whether location is public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got stuck on the same issue. 
As I understand from end of [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user) access token has to include user_location and user_hometown permissions. Tried it in [api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) but had no success - still was not able to see location information through api for users that had this info visible on their profile page.

update: answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10790963/1391947) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12557396/1391947) suggest that data access through api / app is more restricted than through webpage to prevent web mining. I assume it is the case regardless you use user or app permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a user access token then you might need to switch to using an app access token retrieved by a call like:

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
grant_type=client_credentials`

Comment: Originally yes, I was using a user access token. However, even if I request (and then use) an app access token per your instructions, the fields are missing from the user response.